# Import of 200+ sermons

Tags: media, media-library, import, bulk-import

While this not a Development-specific question for WordPress, I am looking for a way to import 200+ sermons for our church website..

I have updated the mp3 files wtih mp3tag and all look good.

I am trying to bring these over from a Concrete5 to a WordPress instance.

I don't want to have to code/update all of these in WordPress.

I have looked at a number of Sermon Managers for WordPress including - https://wordpress.org/plugins/sermon-manager-for-wordpress/ which has a mass-import module, but does not do a very good job.

Thanks.

Comment: If they're all MP3 you could treat it as if you're importing a podcast? There's probably more support for that. But the sermons plugin author seems friendly - you could take your feedback to him and see if he'll help you improve it.

Comment: That is probably the best way to handle this.  Thanks.